# Mahopanisad and the Samaveda recensions

Tags: upanishads, sama-veda

The question is - in which recension of Sama Veda does The Mahopanisad occur? I didn't find it in the (currently available texts of) Ranayaniya, and Kauthuma,though this Upanisad is classified in the same category as upanisads of Sama Veda. I have not been able to check any authentic source of Talavakara yet.

If any one knows this for sure, I would appreciate the source / reference. Thanks in advance.

PS: While I am grateful for any references, I am really looking for a printed publication, or an online source with an endorsement of an institution. Blog articles from various individuals, though some of them are quite good, some times don't provide the necessary levels of quality in evidence and traceability. But like I said, I am thankful for any references.